# Replaced carpet with laminated veneer plank flooring - now there is a gap between the casing and floor

Tags: flooring, trim, laminate-floor

I have removed the carpet from my living room and am preparing to install LVP. The problem is that the door casing is too high. There is a 1/4" gap between the bottom of the casing and the LVP. There is also a 1/4" gap between the LVP and the base molding, but that will be concealed with shoe molding.

I could put down some 1/4" underlayment, but that is a lot of work. The doors are split-jam, so removing the casing could cause a bit of trouble as well. There are 7 doors in this room and the adjacent hallway that would need to be addressed.

Is there another solution to conceal that gap?

Comment: Either apply the underlayment, slather paintable silicone, cut 1/4 inch pieces of door casing and do your best to install them, or just ignore it; you'll get used to it as time passes.

Comment: You could look into casing kickers https://casingkickers.com/